# What happens if a thread re-assigns a variable in java?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

I want to know if the following (contrived) example is thread safe:

```
public class SpringSingleton
{

    private MyObject _myObject = new MyObject("hello");

    public void useObject()
    {
        _myObject.doSomethingCool();
    }

    public void changeObject()
    {
        _myObject = new MyObject("goodbye");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Have multiple threads, some using and some changing the object
    }

}
```

My main question is: what will happen when one thread tries to call `useObject()` at the same time another thread tries to call `changeObject()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning a reference is an atomic operation. You can never see a half-assigned reference. So the thread calling the `doSomethingCool()` method will either call it on the old reference, or on the new one.

But that doesn't make the code thread-safe. You can also have visibility problems: the thread reading the reference might see an old one even though  the thread has already written a new reference. To solve that problem, you need to make the field volatile, or to wrap it into an AtomicReference, or to synchronize all accesses to the field.

Also note that if you ever change the code to

```
_myObject.doSomethingCool();
_myObject.doSomethingElse();
```

then you'll have another problem: the first call might be done on the old object, and the second on the new one. If coherence is necessary between these two calls, then those two calls, as well as every other interaction with _myObject, should be wrapped into a synchronized block (using the same lock).

Answer (score 0):

If one thread tries to call `useObject()` at the same time another thread tries to call `changeObject()`, then the behavior is non-deterministic, the thread calling `useObject()` might see the old or the new value.

Whether or not it is "safe" depends on what behavior you desire.
It might not matter to your code which value it sees, in a short period of time.